# Redirect to sub page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have gitpage with structure:

> pages\
>
> ------other-page-a\
>
> -------------------index.html
>
> ------other-page-b\
>
> -------------------index.html
>
> ------other-page-c\
>
> ------------------- ...
>
> static\
>
> asset-manifest.json\
>
> favicon.ico\
>
> index.html\
>
> manifest.json\
>
> service-worker.js\

Main page is react app but some pages in "pages" folder not.

I try to redirect using

```
   <div
              className="button"
              onClick={() =>
                (window.location.replace = https://stepanvanzuriak.github.io/pages/newspaper
                )
              }
            >
```

But this not work, link changes but page not

**SOLUTION**: **Make eject** and remove `navigateFallback` in `SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin`

Comment: have you tried onClick={() => window.location.replace('http://whateverurl')} ?

Comment: @thsorens Yes, same result, link changes but page not

Comment: What element are you using for the onClick? for <a, it needs to be handled a bit differently

Comment: @thsorens `div`

Comment: are you using some kind of client-side router?

Comment: @thsorens In my code i'ts (window.location.replace = this.state.projectLinks[
                  this.state.projectTitle
                ])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163928/discussion-between-thsorens-and-stepan-vanzuriak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to reach a document thats not exposed from the node-server. Since the server is probably setup with a fallback (returning the same index.html no matter what url you put in). Every request will then return the main-index with the react-app in it. Adding the other folders as static folders to be exposed in the node server should do the trick